# String[] in DevicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden

Tags: android

I want to hide (disable) applications using a String array, but setApplicationHidden accepts only String.
Can I convert this array into String and hide all applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using for loop

Ex:

> String[] appToHideList = getListHowEverYouWant();
>
> for(String appName : appToHideList){ setApplicationHidden(appName); }

Your questions was not clearly explained what are you trying to achieve but this might help you ;